# Nodejs application exits with code 0 without explicit calls

Tags: node.js, sqlite, exit

My application is a nodejs (v 6.9.4) application and it uses express 4.x and mapbox/node-sqlite3. It runs under linux.
After some times the application exits with code 0.
No explicit calls to process.exit() in my code.

The application is:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    MainLogger.errorException(err, "Process.uncaughtException");
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    MainLogger.error(reason, p);
});

process.on('exit', function (code) {
    MainLogger.warn("Process exited with code " + code);
});

startup();
```

The log shows only:

Process exited with code 0

Is there a way to understand why application exits? I think that the exit is caused by a npm module critical error.
How can i inspect this kind of error?

Comment: Is this a child process?

Comment: no...it's the main process launched by run levels at os startup

Comment: Does MainLogger.error etc do async? It will only run synchronously. I am having a similar issue though

Comment: Sync or async code in MainLogger.error leads to the same result (process exit with code 0). I suspect a big error on a library (probably node-schedule or mapbox/sqlite3). I'm invastigating on this error ...